# Coroutine causes crash in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash, coroutine

I added following function to my script and it causes crash in unity.

```
public void AddCurrentFrameToVideo()
{
    _addFrameFunctionHasBeenCalled = true;

    using (var encoder = new MediaEncoder(encodedFilePath, videoAttr, audioAttr))
    using (var audioBuffer = new NativeArray<float>(sampleFramesPerVideoFrame, Allocator.Temp))
    {

        IEnumerator SetFrame()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            encoder.AddFrame(tex);
            encoder.AddSamples(audioBuffer);
            if (recordingButtonHasBeenPressed)
            {
                yield return StartCoroutine(SetFrame());
            }
            else
            {
                yield return null;
                yield break;
            }

        }

        IEnumerator mycoroutine;
        mycoroutine = SetFrame();

        if (recordingButtonHasBeenPressed)
        {
            StartCoroutine(mycoroutine);
        }
        else
        {
            StopCoroutine(mycoroutine);
        }

    }

}
```

I call this function in an if statement in Update function. see:

```
void Update()
{
    _currentsframe = Time.frameCount;

    if (recordingButtonHasBeenPressed)
    {
        if (!videoBasicFileHasBeenCreated)
        {
            CreateVideoBasicFile();
        }

        if (!_addFrameFunctionHasBeenCalled)
        {
            AddCurrentFrameToVideo();
        }

    }

}
```

Also I controlled `recordingButtonHasBeenPressed` variable in another script by a button `OnClick()`. see:

```
public void RecordVideo_OnClick()
{
    if (videoIsRecording)
    {
        videoIsRecording = false;
        videoRecordButton.image.sprite = videoButtonIsNotRecordingSprite;

        _myRecorderSc.recordingButtonHasBeenPressed = false;
        _myRecorderSc.videoBasicFileHasBeenCreated = false;
    }
    else
    {
        videoRecordButton.image.sprite = videoButtonIsRecordingSprite;
        _myRecorderSc.recordingButtonHasBeenPressed = true;
        _myRecorderSc.videoBasicFileHasBeenCreated = false;
        videoIsRecording = true;
    }
}
```

I don't know why it crashes unity. I don't think it's an infinity loop.
Also I tested a `DO-While` loop instead of using `Croutine`. see:

```
    using (var encoder = new MediaEncoder(encodedFilePath, videoAttr, audioAttr))
    using (var audioBuffer = new NativeArray<float>(sampleFramesPerVideoFrame, Allocator.Temp))
    {
        do
        {
                encoder.AddFrame(tex);
                encoder.AddSamples(audioBuffer);
        } while (recordingButtonHasBeenPressed);
    }
```

it causes unity crash too.

What should I do? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
    IEnumerator SetFrame()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        encoder.AddFrame(tex);
        encoder.AddSamples(audioBuffer);
        if (recordingButtonHasBeenPressed)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(SetFrame());
        }
     }
```

is a recursive call where you `yield return` the same routine again (which internally `yield return`s the same routine again etc) so it waits until all nested subroutines are finished => So at some point you will get a StackOverflow!

---

This is definitely a closed never ending while loop

```
using (var audioBuffer = new NativeArray<float>(sampleFramesPerVideoFrame, Allocator.Temp))
{
    do
    {
            encoder.AddFrame(tex);
            encoder.AddSamples(audioBuffer);
    } while (recordingButtonHasBeenPressed);
}
```

within the loop the value of `recordingButtonHasBeenPressed` will **never** be changed and Unity/your app immediately freezes forever!

---

What you would want to do instead would be a Coroutine like

```
IEnumerator SetFrame()
{
    // initially wait once
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

    // simply continue to execute the routine until the record shall be stopped
    while(recordingButtonHasBeenPressed)
    {
        encoder.AddFrame(tex);
        encoder.AddSamples(audioBuffer);

        // yield the next frames for 0.3 seconds before checking 
        // recordingButtonHasBeenPressed again
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
    }
}
```

You then wouldn't even need to actively stop it. All you need to do is start it and then in order to interrupt it simply set `recordingButtonHasBeenPressed` to `false`.

---

**Do it event driven**

Now in general instead of using `Update` and multiple controller flag `bool`s you immediately seem to reset again once a method gets called here I would rather make the entire code **event driven** and called **once** when the button is called. This would prevent having concurrent routines running by accident and make the whole thing way better to read and maintain.

I don't know your full code but it might look something like

```
public void RecordVideo_OnClick()
{
    // invert the toggle flag
    videoIsRecording = !videoIsRecording;

    // depending on the new flag value chose the sprite
    videoRecordButton.image.sprite = videoIsRecording ? videoButtonIsRecordingSprite : videoButtonIsNotRecordingSprite;

    if (!videoIsRecording)
    {
        _myRecorderSc.StopRecording();
    }
    else
    {
        _myRecorderSc.StartRecoring();
    }
}
```

and then in the recorder script you would only need

```
public void StartRecording()
{
    if(!recording)
    {
        StartCoroutine(RecorderRoutine);
    }
}

public void StopRecording()
{
    recording = false;
}

// flag to interrupt running record
private bool recording;

private IEnumerator RecorderRoutine()
{
    // Just in case prevent concurrent routines
    if(recording) yield break;
    recording = true;

    // initialize your file
    CreateVideoBasicFile();    

    // initially wait once
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

    using (var encoder = new MediaEncoder(encodedFilePath, videoAttr, audioAttr))
    using (var audioBuffer = new NativeArray<float>(sampleFramesPerVideoFrame, Allocator.Temp))
    {
        // simply continue to execute the routine until the record shall be stopped
        while(recording)
        {
            encoder.AddFrame(tex);
            encoder.AddSamples(audioBuffer);

            // yield the next frames for 0.3 seconds before checking 
            // recordingButtonHasBeenPressed again
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        }
    }

    recording = false;
}
```

Comment: I did what you told, but unity didn't add any frame to video. It seems "encoder.AddFrame" doesn't work.

Comment: I fixed it. I set the value of `recordingButtonHasBeenPressed` "true" before calling `StartRecording()` and "false" before calling `StopRecording`. It works, but when I recieved an error: "The NativeArray has been deallocated, it is not allowed to access it". This way unity just add one frame to video, before adding second frame this error has been appeared.

Comment: sorry that was actually due to a typo ^^ in the while condition it should be just `recording`